# javax.swing.JTable; Records Validating causes Performance issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable

javax.swing.JTable;  Records Validating causes Performance issue
I am trying to validate each  Record from JTable  using for loop  , when JTable having Many records it is taking lot of time please suggest me better approach.
Please find below sample code snippet .Thanks In advance.

```
            JTable tblReceipt = getTblReceive();
                    tblReceipt.removeEditor();
                    boolean allLineCheck = true;


                    for (int row = 0; row < tblReceipt.getRowCount(); row++)
                    {
                        String issueQty = (String) tblReceipt.getValueAt(row, 5);
                        String receiveQty = (String) tblReceipt.getValueAt(row, 6);
                        String itemNo = (String) tblReceipt.getValueAt(row, 0);
                        double dIssueQty = Common.toDouble(issueQty);
                        double dReceiveQty = Common.toDouble(receiveQty);


                        double qty = 1.0;// initial one quantity
                        qty = qty / Math.pow(10, itmDecimal);

                        if (dReceiveQty > dIssueQty)
                        {
                            getProgressBar().setVisible(false);
                            Common.displayConfirmDialog()

                            // Qty exceeds the available qty


                        }
                        else if (itmDecimal == 0 && (dReceiveQty >= 0.0000001 && dReceiveQty <= 0.1))
                        {

                            Common.displayConfirmDialog();


                            // Invalid quantity

                            return false;
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: What if you move the double qty = 1.0;// initial one quantity
                        qty = qty / Math.pow(10, itmDecimal); out of the for loop?

Comment: How many is "many"? 1000? 1000000? Do you use an own `TableModel`?

Comment: yes I can  move the double qty = 1.0;// initial one quantity qty = qty / Math.pow(10, itmDecimal)  and    10000 records will be there max

Comment: Yes Im using my own table model

Comment: A [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) may help us isolate the issue.

Comment: In this scenario I cant provide a compile code because this method  depends on other classes